# How do I configure which Linux distribution WSL uses?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have two Linux subsystems install `Ubuntu 18.04` and `Kali Linux`.  Presently when I run `wsl ls ~` it executes on `Kali Linux` how do I instruct `wsl.exe` to execute commands on `Ubuntu 18.04`?

From command prompt:

```
C:\>wsl ls ~/
kali

C:\>
```

From Ubuntu 18.04:

```
colton@DESKTOP-SHJ6OK8:~$ ls ~
Ubuntu
colton@DESKTOP-SHJ6OK8:~$
```

From Kali:

```
colton@DESKTOP-SHJ6OK8:~$ ls ~
kali
colton@DESKTOP-SHJ6OK8:~$
```

Comment: According to https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config , you can run the command "wslconfig /setdefault name".  Replace name with the appropriate distribution name, probably "ubuntu" for you.  I don't have multiple subsystems installed so can't verify, but if that works for you, please create that Answer below.

Comment: Command: `wsl.exe --distribution <distro-name>`.

Answer (score 0):

You may enter the shell of a distribution from the Start menu :

[image]

You may enter the shell from the command-line by running :

```
ubuntu.exe
```

You may execute one particular WSL command from the command-line, returning
to the command-line prompt, by running :

```
ubuntu.exe run ls ~/
```